# VC++ mouse events

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mouseevent

I want to write a console program for mouse events (Only mouse scroll). How do I do it in VC++? The application will listen only to scroll events.

Description: If the user scrolls down, the Desktop window fades down, and fades-in when user scrolls up.

Here I just need to know to to listen to mouse events in console app.

Note: I am developing using win32 API, and for development environment I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually done this myself. It seems that a console application responding to mouse events almost belies its nature and intended purpose. Generally, you would only need to respond to keyboard input from a console app and leave the mouse stuff to a GUI app.

That being said, [this tutorial](http://www.adrianxw.dk/SoftwareSite/Consoles/Consoles5.html) indicates that it is in fact possible to capture these mouse events from a Win32 console application. Generally, the suggestion is to use the [`ReadConsoleInput` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961.aspx) and extract the information of interest from the `INPUT_RECORD` structure that it fills. The only tricky thing is that the call to `ReadConsoleInput` is a *blocking* call, which means it will not return until there is an input event fired. You'll need to structure your application's code accordingly. Mouse events are covered in detail about 3/4 of the way down the page.

Comment: @Cody: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I liked your explanation in first para.

Comment: @Ashwin: Glad that works for you. The first thing that crossed my mind was a global hook which is probably not the best solution, so I learned something new as well!

Comment: @Cody: I did some play with global hooks and it crashed and I could not get it working as the way I needed. This works nice. and it keeps my design simple.

Comment: @Cody: Hey Cody, I am passionate to know, is there any API or any module that is generic to Linux and Windows? To handle mouse events.

Comment: @Ashwin: I am definitely not a Linux programmer, so I'm probably not the best one to ask for this. But my best guess tells me that there isn't. Linux and Windows handle I/O differently, and it's unlikely that you'll find a unifying library. But rarely can you compile code *once* for multiple platforms, so I'm not really sure what the benefit of that would be anyway. Start a new question if you'd like to get input from some more qualified folks.

Comment: @Cody: I figured out a way! May be little/very odd for all.. Whatever! I make a mock-up on using assembly language with help of c-compilers. It worked out on both platforms. It was just a simplest program. Will get a try on handling I/O this weekend.